# Output converted JSON value in Python

Tags: python, json

I have the code to covert this input into json format in python:

```
{ 
    name: (sidney, crosby)
    game: "Hockey"
    type: athlete
},
{ 
    name: (wayne, gretzky)
    game: "Ice Hockey"
    type: athlete
}
```

Code:

```
import json
import os

user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")
assert os.path.exists(user_input), "Invalid file at, " + str(user_input)
f = open(user_input, 'r')
content = f.read()

def parse_records(txt):
    reclines = []
    for line in txt.split('\n'):
        if ':' not in line:
            if reclines:
                yield reclines
                reclines = []
        else:
            reclines.append(line)

def parse_fields(reclines):
    res = {}
    for line in reclines:
        key, val = line.strip().rstrip(',').split(':', 1)
        res[key.strip()] = val.strip()
    return res

res = []
for rec in parse_records(content):
    res.append(parse_fields(rec))

print(json.dumps(res, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "(sidney, crosby)",
        "game": "\"Hockey\"",
        "type": "athlete"
    },
    {
        "name": "(wayne, gretzky)",
        "game": "\"Ice Hockey\"",
        "type": "athlete"
    }
]
```

I want to output specific json value of name ie:

```
(sidney, crosby), athlete
(wayne, gretzky), athlete
```

I added these lines

```
 res = []
for rec in parse_records(content):
    res.append(parse_fields(rec))

    my_json = json.load(res)
for data in my_json:
    print(data["name"], data["type"])
```

but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\670274890\PycharmProjects\Proj\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    my_json = json.load(res)
  File "C:\Users\670274890\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Would I need to store the converted json file and then parse it to output the specific values or is there a way to fix up the last few lines I wrote to get the desired output?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Your error comes from passing `res` to `json.load()`. `res` is a list, which can be converted to a `json` string using: `json.dumps(res)`. This string can be written to a file, for example, but since you seem to want to iterate over something and print something out you should look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `json` once you have your `res` list. You just iterate over that list printing what you need:

```py
for person in res:
    print(person["name"], person["type"])
```

If you need to save `res` to a file, then `json` format seems reasonable. You should have this at the end of your program:

```py
with open('output.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dumps(res, file, indent=4)
```

Comment: works beautifully, thank you!!